# Getting multiple values returned from a $.ajax POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have some ajax code that executes on mouseclick. It calls a file called update.php that does a bunch of stuff, including checking for user permissions, numerous database calls, etc.  In the end, I also want to be able to return a few variables from PHP for the callback to use, but not sure how to reference them - or if there's a better way to return this info.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "update.php",
data: dataString,
success: callback 

});

function callback(data, status)
{
// $("div").text(data);
$("div.numbert").text("[first variable here]");
$("div.numbert2").text("[second variable here]");
        }
```

From my update.php file (some snippets):

```
    if ($check_access > 0)
    {
// Update database 

$sql = "UPDATE db SET access = '1' WHERE user = '$user'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());


// Give access - function returns data to variable
$value = GiveAccess($user);


// Email - function returns data to variable
$emaillist = emailAdmins($user);    

    } else {

$message = "Sorry you do not have access";
    }
```

So I'd like to figure out how to use the variables $message, $value and $emaillist in my callback if possible.

I'm wondering if I just need to make multiple $.ajax POST calls, with each .php function that returns a variable having it's own call?

Thanks!

---

### ----UPDATE-------

Updated code trying to use the json methods - thanks for all the help - but seems I'm missing one last thing.

```
    $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "update.php",
data: dataString,
dataType: 'json',
    success: callback 

});

function callback(data, status)
{
// $("div").text(data);
$("div.numbert").text(data.value);
$("div.numbert2").text(data.emaillist);
```

and update.php:

```
    $storage = array();
// Update database 

$sql = "UPDATE db SET access = '1' WHERE user = '$user'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());


// Give access - function returns data to variable
$storage['value'] = "some user";


// Email - function returns data to variable
    $storage['emaillist'] = "some stuff";   

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($storage);
    exit(0);
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a JSON wrapper:

```
$messages = array();
$messages['value'] = GiveAccess($user);
$messages['emaillist'] = emailAdmins($user);
$messages['message'] = "Sorry you do not have access";

echo json_encode($messages);
```

And then simply use:

```
data.value    data.emaillist    data.message
```

in your Javascript.

Comment: original post updated with new code...close but not working quite yet...thanks again.

Comment: needed to exclude the header() call as suggested below - your code with the addition of dataType: 'json' in the $.ajax did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way would be to use JSON...

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "update.php",
data: dataString,
dataType: 'json',
success: callback 

});

function callback(data, status)
{
  // $("div").text(data);
  if(data.error){
    alert(error.message||'Unknown Error');
  } else {
     $("div.numbert").text(data.access||'No value');
     $("div.numbert2").text(data.emailList||'No value');
  }

}
```

PHP:

```
if ($check_access > 0)
    {
// Update database 

$sql = "UPDATE db SET access = '1' WHERE user = '$user'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$responseData = array();


// Give access - function returns data to variable
$responseData['access'] = GiveAccess($user);


// Email - function returns data to variable
$responseData['emailList'] = emailAdmins($user);    

    } else {

$responseData['error'] = array('code' => 403, 'message' => "Sorry you do not have access");
    }

header('Content-type: application/json');
print json_encode($responseData);
exit(0);
```

Comment: What should I do about the error from the header('Content-type): that I receive in my data string:   <b>Warning</b>: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content

Comment: original post updated with new code...close but not working quite yet...thanks again.

Comment: Thanks - your code worked, though I had to remove the header() call in the update.php file for it to work - was getting a warning and it might have been stopping because of that. But working with the other code. Thanks!

Comment: Well ig you got that wanting that means you were sending output before that call. Yo shouldnt be exhoing anything before the header call or anything but the json. If you didnt have any echos or prints in your code then you page was likely generating warnings elsewhere or there was whitespace before opening php tag.

Answer (score 0):

No, just return a JSON object or a dataset that's delimited that you can parse.

Answer (score 0):

You can return your values using json:

```
$storage = array();
 if ($check_access > 0)
    {
// Update database 

$sql = "UPDATE db SET access = '1' WHERE user = '$user'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());


// Give access - function returns data to variable
$value = GiveAccess($user);
$storage['value'] = $value;

// Email - function returns data to variable
$emaillist = emailAdmins($user);  
$storage['emaillist'] = $emaillist;  

    } else {

$message = "Sorry you do not have access";
$storage['message'] = $message;
    }
```

header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8");
    $return = json_encode($storage);
    echo $return;
exit;

You can then iterate over the object and go

```
function callback(data, status)
{
// $("div").text(data);
$("div.numbert").text(data.value);
$("div.numbert2").text(data.emaillist);
        }
```

Comment: weird - after adding the dataType: 'json' to my .ajax, adding the $storage = array(); and sending my varibable (trying one) $storage['value'] = $value; --- i try accessing the variable via this $div("div.numbert").text(data.value); and it doesn't return anything...?

Comment: I will post my updated code - I reverted back to removing the dataType: 'json' and echoing the one variable in my update.php script and it updates via  $div("div.numbert").text(data);

Comment: original post updated with new code...close but not working quite yet...thanks again.